# How to know the difference of GMT and local time in C++ on Solaris?

Tags: c++, time, solaris, gmt, mktime

I like to calculate the difference of local time (in some timezone) and GMT in terms of number of seconds. I use the following code snippet:

```
time_t now = time(0); // GMT
time_t gmnow = mktime(gmtime(&now)); // further convert to GMT presuming now in local
time_t diff = gmnow - now;
```

But, I am getting a wrong difference.
What I am doing here is querying the current time as GMT through time(0). Then presuming that is a local time, I call gmtime to add the GMT difference factor and re-convert to local time using mktime. This should have shown the difference of GMT and my timezone, but it is showing a extra difference of 1 hour (daylight savings).

For example, my current time is Thu Mar 13 04:54:45 EDT 2014
When I get current time as GMT, that should be:
Thu Mar 13 08:55:34 GMT 2014
Considering this is current time, if I call gmtime, this should further proceed, and re-converting back should give me a difference of 4 hr, but I am getting a difference of 5hr.

Is gmtime usage wrong here?
Also, how do I know current time zone as well as time in daylight savings?

Comment: with `time(0)` you are getting the UTC time not GMT

Comment: @elvis.dukaj Yes, correct, but even then my objective is to know difference of GMT and current time with daylight savings adjustments, if any. Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

The following code snippet would solve this:

```
time_t now = time(0); // UTC
time_t diff;
struct tm *ptmgm = gmtime(&now); // further convert to GMT presuming now in local
time_t gmnow = mktime(ptmgm);
diff = gmnow - now;
if (ptmgm->tm_isdst > 0) {
    diff = diff - 60 * 60;
}
```

The trick is to check tm_isdst flag, if applicable and if set, adjust one hour more to diff
This works.
Thanks to all for your time.

Comment: This works for most cases. There are a (very small, rare) set of places that observe other than a 1 hour DST change.

Comment: @Petesh  Could this be any problem while running the portion of code, DST becomes effective, just before, just after in between time_t gmnow = mktime(ptmgm) call is made?

Comment: I think there could be an issue in the spring forward case, where there's a whole hour that simply 'doesn't exist' in localtime - you would have to test it yourself to be certain; but for the fall-back case; I think it's covered by the `tm_isdst` flag. Solaris has the variables `altzone` and `timezone` for the [#seconds of UTC offset in both cases](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5168/6mbb3hrfk/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

This can handle it in the correct way I think:

```
time_t t = time (NULL);
tm * srTM = localtime(&t);
setenv("TZ", "GMT0",1); //Change your timezone to GMT
time_t t2 = mktime(srTM);  
diff = difftime(t2,t);
setenv("TZ", "CET-1CEST-2,M3.5.0/02:00:00,M10.5.0/03:00:00", 1); //Reset your timezone to correct one (here CET)
```